# Recursive .groupby to achieve a dict of dicts of dicts

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have following sample dataset as a pandas DataFrame, each `key` is unique to its `namespace` and each `value` is also unique to its `key`:

|  | image | namespace | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | img1 | ns1 | organism | human |
| 1 | img1 | ns1 | organ | liver |
| 2 | img1 | ns2 | microscope | confocal |
| 3 | img2 | ns2 | microscope | confocal |
| 4 | img2 | ns2 | technique | widefield |
| 5 | img2 | ns2 | technique | phase-contrast |
| 6 | img2 | ns4 | analysis | segmentation |

and I try to get a dict of dicts of dicts of list out of it.
The ideal outcome would look like:

```
{"img1":{"ns1":{"organism":["human"],"organ":["liver"]},
"ns2":{"microscope":["confocal"]}},
"img2":{"ns2":{"microscope":["confocal"],"technique":["widefield","phase-contrast"]},
"ns4":{"analysis":["segmentation"]}}}
```

I am sure I can somehow achieve this by recursive `.groupby` but I have tried and failed multiple times.
Please, can someone more competent point out an obvious answer?

Comment: Please edit your post to include your attempted code. We can then show you where you're going wrong

Comment: Do you need a Pandas based answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not being a Pandas wizard, I would simply iterate over the rows using `setdefault()` to build your nested dictionary. In fact, I might be tempted to bypass pandas altogether.

```py
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame([
    {"image": "img1", "namespace": "ns1", "key": "organism", "value": "human"},
    {"image": "img1", "namespace": "ns1", "key": "organ", "value": "liver"},
    {"image": "img1", "namespace": "ns2", "key": "microscope", "value": "confocal"},
    {"image": "img2", "namespace": "ns2", "key": "microscope", "value": "confocal"},
    {"image": "img2", "namespace": "ns2", "key": "technique", "value": "widefield"},
    {"image": "img2", "namespace": "ns2", "key": "technique", "value": "phase-contrast"},
    {"image": "img2", "namespace": "ns4", "key": "analysis", "value": "segmentation"},
])

results = {}
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    results \
        .setdefault(row["image"], {}) \
        .setdefault(row["namespace"], {}) \
        .setdefault(row["key"], []) \
        .append(row["value"])

import json  
print(json.dumps(results, indent=4))
```

That will give you:

```
{
    "img1": {
        "ns1": {
            "organism": [
                "human"
            ],
            "organ": [
                "liver"
            ]
        },
        "ns2": {
            "microscope": [
                "confocal"
            ]
        }
    },
    "img2": {
        "ns2": {
            "microscope": [
                "confocal"
            ],
            "technique": [
                "widefield",
                "phase-contrast"
            ]
        },
        "ns4": {
            "analysis": [
                "segmentation"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume all 3 answers are correct, but yours was the easiest to understand for me as an only intermediate Python programmer.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do a recursive `groupby`, then you could try (`df` your dataframe):

```py
def nest_it(df, level=1):
    if level == 3:
        return df.groupby(df.columns[0])[df.columns[1]].agg(list).to_dict()
    return {key: nest_it(sdf[sdf.columns[1:]], level=level+1)
            for key, sdf in df.groupby(df.columns[0])}

result = nest_it(df)
```

Result for the sample:

```py
{'img1': {'ns1': {'organ': ['liver'], 'organism': ['human']},
          'ns2': {'microscope': ['confocal']}},
 'img2': {'ns2': {'microscope': ['confocal'],
                  'technique': ['widefield', 'phase-contrast']},
          'ns4': {'analysis': ['segmentation']}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not using recursive groupby, but the idea is to reshape your dataframe into a multi-index dataframe wherein you can make use of the built-in to_dict function.

First, transform your df using a single group by across multiple columns and unstack it.

```
>>> df
  image namespace         key           value
0  img1       ns1    organism           human
1  img1       ns1       organ           liver
2  img1       ns2  microscope        confocal
3  img2       ns2  microscope        confocal
4  img2       ns2   technique       widefield
5  img2       ns2   technique  phase-contrast
6  img2       ns4    analysis    segmentation
>>> tbl_xform = df.groupby(['image', 'namespace', 'key'])['value'].agg(lambda x: list(set(x))).unstack()
>>> tbl_xform
key                    analysis  microscope    organ organism                    technique
image namespace
img1  ns1                   NaN         NaN  [liver]  [human]                          NaN
      ns2                   NaN  [confocal]      NaN      NaN                          NaN
img2  ns2                   NaN  [confocal]      NaN      NaN  [widefield, phase-contrast]
      ns4        [segmentation]         NaN      NaN      NaN                          NaN
>>>
```

For each main level (image) of the reshaped dataframe's index, we can use xs and to_dict discarding the nan along the way.

```
>>> my_dict = {image: tbl_xform.xs(image).apply(lambda x : x.dropna().to_dict(),axis=1).to_dict() for image in tbl_xform.index.levels[0]}
>>> my_dict
{'img1': {'ns1': {'organ': ['liver'], 'organism': ['human']}, 'ns2': {'microscope': ['confocal']}}, 'img2': {'ns2': {'microscope': ['confocal'], 'technique': ['widefield', 'phase-contrast']}, 'ns4': {'analysis': ['segmentation']}}}
```